# Google Sheets Sumifs with date condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs, google-sheets-query

I'm getting an error when trying to grab the money I have spent for a month on another Google Sheet using `SUMIFS` formula. I'm new to writing formulas and this is the first bottleneck I haven't been able to find.

I'm trying to write a formula in my google sheet but getting an error. I'm new at this so forgive me.

In the Google Sheet, I have three Sheets (Summary, which is main), Leads and Spend.

I'm trying to write a formula to grab how much I spent for a particular month. In the Spend sheet, I have column for the date, name and dollar amount.

Here is the formula I have tried without luck.

```
Spend!G:G = Column with text for type of spend (Google PPC)
Spend!E:E = Column with cost of each spend
Spend!A:A = Column with the date
```

---

```
=SUMIFS(Spend!G:G,"Google PPC",Spend!E:E,Spend!A:A,">=1/1/2019", Spend!A:A,"<=1/31/2019")
```

It should just give me a total amount spent on the dates given. But I get an error that says "array arguments to `SUMIFS` are of different size"

Answer (score 1):

The first argument should be the range of cells to sum. Then follow a series of ranges and criteria.

```
=SUMIFS(Spend!E:E, 
        Spend!G:G,"Google PPC",
        Spend!A:A,">=1/1/2019", 
        Spend!A:A,"<=1/31/2019")
```

see: [SUMIFS documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

a bit different approach would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(Spend!A:G, "select E where year(A)=2019 and month(A)+1=1"))
```

[image]