# How to extract Google Sheets data, aggregated by month?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, spreadsheet

Working in Google Sheets, I want to create a pivot table or some sort of separate tab/sheet that will automatically keep a running tally of all dollar amounts by month.

I've read these 3 questions:

- [Google Sheets Sumifs with date condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381986/google-sheets-sumifs-with-date-condition)
- [Google Sheets - Sum Elements of a Column's Range by Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67613261/google-sheets-sum-elements-of-a-columns-range-by-month)
- [Getting sum of the amount per month - Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959278/getting-sum-of-the-amount-per-month-google-sheet)

They lead me to believe I could write formulas to filter & sum by date. But I think I'd have to keep adding new month-rows as my original table grows...right?

Here's my table:

| Date | Amount | Date | Amount | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan, 2024 | $1,490.83 | Feb, 2024 | $372.71 | Mar, 2024 | $372.71 |
| Jan, 2024 | $1,385.83 | Feb, 2024 | $346.46 | May, 2024 | $346.46 |
| Mar, 2024 | $75.00 | Apr, 2024 | $18.75 | May, 2024 | $18.75 |
| Mar, 2024 | $150.00 | Apr, 2024 | $37.50 | May, 2024 | $37.50 |
| Mar, 2024 | $1,500.00 | Apr, 2024 | $375.00 | May, 2024 | $375.00 |

Hoping to automatically output...

| Month | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Jan, 2024 | $2,876.67 |
| Feb, 2024 | $719.17 |
| Mar, 2024 | $2,444.17 |
| Apr, 2024 | $431.25 |
| May, 2024 | $431.25 |

I tried to create a pivot table, but I'm not good at them and it just started listing all the months again, without aggregating their dollar values.

The layout of the original table is not editable, so I can’t align or order the months.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Suppose you copy your example sheet to column `A:F`

In `H1`, enter

```
={"Date";unique(flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Date")))}
```

and then in `I1`, enter

```
={"Total";map(H2:H,lambda(c,if(isblank(c),,sum(filter(flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Amount")),flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Date"))=c)))))}
```

You can "cut" both cells *together* and "paste" in any location you need -- but they should be outside your data columns, ie. `A:F`.

---

**Explanations**

To get the unique months under one date column, you can use [`unique`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en). For example,

```
=unique(A2:A)
```

Since your data entries repeat across multiple columns (which I do advise against), you can aggregate all dates using [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en&sjid=8538421562534290049-NC) and [`flatten`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en). For example,

```
=flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Date"))
```

In the above, the implicit assumption from your sheet is that the date columns *always* have a header cell containing exactly the text `"Date"`.

Thus, if you put in cell `H1`

```
unique(flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Date")))
```

you will get in column H a column of dates in the format of `month-name, year`, and the adherence to this format of dates is another implicit assumption from your sheet.

Note that the range for the data entries is `A2:F`, which does not specify the end row. That is intentional and it allows you to grow your data tab without changing the formula. (Again, I advise growing the data tab vertically.)

Assuming your "Amount" columns *always* come with a header cell containing the text `"Amount"`, you can then use the same functions to aggregate all the dollar amount:

```
flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Amount"))
```

Thus, altogether, you can use `filter` on the "Amount" cells based on "Date" cells. For example, in cell `I1`, you may enter,

```
=sum(filter(flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Amount")),flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Date"))=H1))
```

and the resulting figure is the total amount for Jan, 2024.

Note that the implicit assumption from your sheet is that your data always has Date-Amount pairings and nothing else. Amount can be zero or empty of course. But the format is adhered to.

At this point, you can "drag" the formula down if you wish and complete the task at hand.

You can also centralize the formulas to one single cell using [`map`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en&sjid=8538421562534290049-NC) and enter in cell `I1` the following formula:

```
=map(H1:H,lambda(c,if(isblank(c),,sum(filter(flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Amount")),flatten(filter(A2:F,A1:F1="Date"))=c)))))
```

where the range `H1:H` does not have an end row, similar to earlier, which allows for growing your data tab. In order to allow for the lack of end row, `if(isblank(),...` is used to ignore empty rows. This particular position of `if(isblank()` within the `lambda` function is what I have experimented and found to be efficient with Google Sheet. Earlier we didn't need it because `filter` already detects end row.

And you completed the task at hand. In the TL;DR answer section, I added header cells that you specified in your example output. Using the array concatenation syntax `{...;...}`.

Note how all original formatting is preserved in the newly created column H and column I. That is a feature of using these built-in functions.

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm close, but not 100% there. [Here's a copy of my original table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B_Nzu8iyI1t5zEk9UNmwvS_GKKINdWghlH9HIl9Ppuc/edit#gid=0)

You’ll see that my Date and Amount cells are always named accordingly, but they start on J6 and extend to AA.

Also, I need the "by month" calculations to live on a separate sheet, labelled "Commission by Month."

Can you recommend edits to your original answer to fit this sheet setup?

And THANK YOU again!!

Comment: @T11-TJK: I don't think it is appropriate to edit answers to address new questions in the form of comments. (I also advise against editing your original question at this point, which is one day after posting and a few answers are already received.) The edits will not make sense without reading your comment here but that's not how StackOverflow is used.

Comment: @T11-TJK: The reason the formulas do not work in your new sheet is that your new sheet breaks the implicit assumption in your original question on date formatting. Your dates in your new sheet are never actually months. To adapt the formulas, there are two easy ways. 1) Change your "Date" collects to contain only month and year. Such as by `=date(year(...),month(...),1))` and keep the same formulas for the aggregate; 2) Change the aggregate formula to compare month and year.

Comment: @T11-TJK: One (inefficient) example of 2) is `={"Month";unique(flatten(filter(arrayformula(if(isblank(J7:AA),,date(year(J7:AA),month(J7:AA),1))),J6:AA6="Date")))}` and `{Total; =map(T2:T,lambda(c,if(isblank(c),,sum(filter(flatten(filter(J7:AA,J6:AA6="Amt")),flatten(filter(arrayformula(if(isblank(J7:AA),,date(year(J7:AA),month(J7:AA),1))),J6:AA6="Date"))=c)))))}`.

Comment: @T11-TJK: Another reason is that your new sheet broke away from the format of using text "Amount" and used "Amt" instead. [This](https://i.imgur.com/Iv98Z4x.png) is the result of using the formula in the comment above where the issues were fixed. You can check if the amounts add up.

Comment: @T11-TJK: Separately, when sharing example sheet on StackOverflow, please make the sheet editable by link. Right now, your new sheet is comment only.

Comment: You’ve been incredibly helpful, thank you— I still can’t get it to work. I opened up the permissions on the Google Sheet. Might you be willing to add the formulas in there? Again, thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: @T11-TJK: I put in the correct ranges in all the formulas. The updated original is in column A & B. You can see that the new formulas in column D & E work without changing the data in your new sheet. However, I expect the formula to be computationally inefficient. I changed some of your "Date" columns to contain only month and year. (Check the formulas in column J to M in !Deals.) In the last set of formulas in column G & H, I copied the original and limited the range to column J to M. You can see that the formulas work. I expect this route to yield a more responsive sheet.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is completely perfect for what I’ve asked so far.

I opened a second thread for a new/related question, about grouping these month/amount values by Name. Could you take a look?

New thread is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77834998/how-to-extract-google-sheets-data-aggregated-by-month-grouped-by-cell-value

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ, wraprows(tocol(A2:F),2),
     query(Σ,"select Col1,sum(Col2) Where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"))
```

[image]